# Flickering initial Storyboard content before viewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm scratching my head for days already trying to understand what I observe. I'm doing iOS development for many ears and I believe I have never seen such effect:

Basically for all ViewControllers I have in the app (defined in a Storyboard), when the view appears, the initial storyboard defined content/layout is displayed for a second and then the proper content appears.

I'm doing all UI element setup is `viewDidLoad()` so I expect when content appears it must be already properly configured.

No idea what it can be. Changes in Swift/Xcode? Some hidden project configuration?

Comment: This way too little information to give an answer. Are you using anything unusual or custom at all?

Comment: I'm aware my case is too obscure. I have just lost hope to understand this. :/

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me like you are displaying your vc too soon,
it might be that your initial setup is too costly, or that you are calling a service to get that initial data and until the response arrives your vc is still 'flickering' as you put it. 
this is usually solved by presenting a loader and making the actual transition only once you are finished with the initialization / data getting phase.
some initializations are more costly than others.